# JMeter - Resource string not found error

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter 3.2 r1790748 and getting the below messages in the log.

```
2017-08-25 11:41:52,208 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [monitor_health_title]
2017-08-25 11:41:52,208 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [monitor_health_title]
2017-08-25 11:41:52,208 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [monitor_equation_healthy]
2017-08-25 11:41:52,208 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [monitor_equation_active]
2017-08-25 11:41:52,208 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [monitor_equation_warning]
2017-08-25 11:41:52,208 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [monitor_equation_dead]
2017-08-25 11:41:52,208 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [monitor_equation_load]
2017-08-25 11:41:52,224 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [monitor_health_tab_title]
2017-08-25 11:41:52,224 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [monitor_legend_health]
2017-08-25 11:41:52,224 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [monitor_legend_load]
2017-08-25 11:41:52,224 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [monitor_legend_memory_per]
2017-08-25 11:41:52,224 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [monitor_legend_thread_per]
2017-08-25 11:41:52,224 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [monitor_label_left_top]
2017-08-25 11:41:52,224 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [monitor_label_left_middle]
2017-08-25 11:41:52,224 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [monitor_label_left_bottom]
2017-08-25 11:41:52,224 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [monitor_label_right_healthy]
2017-08-25 11:41:52,224 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [monitor_label_right_dead]
2017-08-25 11:41:52,224 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [monitor_performance_title]
2017-08-25 11:41:52,224 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [monitor_performance_servers]
2017-08-25 11:41:52,224 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [monitor_performance_tab_title]
2017-08-25 11:41:52,224 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [monitor_label_prefix]
2017-08-25 11:41:52,239 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [monitor_health_title]
2017-08-25 11:41:52,239 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [monitor_health_title]
2017-08-25 11:41:52,427 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [monitor_health_title]
2017-08-25 11:41:52,427 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [monitor_health_title]
2017-08-25 11:41:52,427 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [monitor_health_title]
2017-08-25 11:41:52,427 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [monitor_health_title]
2017-08-25 11:41:52,427 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [monitor_health_title]
2017-08-25 11:41:52,443 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [monitor_health_title]
2017-08-25 11:41:52,521 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [monitor_health_title]
```

Does anyone know what are these errors are about and how to resolve them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be having a component of a 3rd Party plugin that relies on resources of a removed component called **Monitor Results**.

See:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60423

And release notes of JMeter 3.2 in section **Removed elements or functions**:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html#Incompatible%20changes

> Bug 60423 - Drop Monitor Results listener

Comment: It was an older version of the plugin manager that was causing the error.