# JMeter 5.0 / "JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found" @ Aggregate Report

Tags: jmeter

JMeter 5.0 r1840935 @ Win 7 64 Bit

All the time when I click on the Aggregate Report I'm getting about 10 Error-Message-Lines in the Log-Window ...

Is this a problem just on my PC or does it happen on your PC too?

All other things in JMeter are working very fine.

Maybe it has to do with this entry but I'm not enough experienced to understand it:

[JMeter - Resource string not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45884051/jmeter-resource-string-not-found-error)

I appreciate your help.

Kind regards
Joe

=======================================

> 2019-01-22 20:47:16,976 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource
>   string not found: [99%*line] 2019-01-22 20:47:16,976 WARN
>   o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [min]
>   2019-01-22 20:47:16,976 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource
>   string not found: [error*%] 2019-01-22 20:47:16,976 WARN
>   o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [throughput]
>   2019-01-22 20:47:16,976 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource
>   string not found: [received_kb/sec] 2019-01-22 20:47:16,976 WARN
>   o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [sent_kb/sec]
>   2019-01-22 20:58:54,822 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource
>   string not found: [label] 2019-01-22 20:58:54,822 WARN
>   o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [#_samples]
>   2019-01-22 20:58:54,822 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource
>   string not found: [median] 2019-01-22 20:58:54,822 WARN
>   o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [90%_line]
>   2019-01-22 20:58:54,822 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource
>   string not found: [95%_line] 2019-01-22 20:58:54,822 WARN
>   o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [99%*line]
>   2019-01-22 20:58:54,822 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource
>   string not found: [min] 2019-01-22 20:58:54,822 WARN
>   o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [error*%]
>   2019-01-22 20:58:54,822 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource
>   string not found: [throughput] 2019-01-22 20:58:54,822 WARN
>   o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found:
>   [received_kb/sec] 2019-01-22 20:58:54,822 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils:
>   ERROR! Resource string not found: [sent_kb/sec]

=======================================

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62896

Which is already fixed in nightly build and will be in 5.1:

- https://ci.apache.org/projects/jmeter/nightlies/